# django request in template

Tags: django, request

I've enabled the Django request processor

```py
TEMPLATE_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Still I don't have to request variable available in templates. I've to manually pass it. Using Django 1.0.2. Everywhere on web it seems it's only about enabled request processor.

Also I am using `RequestContext` as:

```
 return render_to_response(
    'profile.html',
    {
        'persons':Person.objects.all(),
        'person':Person.objects.get(id=id),
         'request':request,
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

No luck.

ohh darn the new name for that is `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: Why are you letting the template know anything about the request?

Comment: easy : i need to know the path *URL* of the request for dynamic navigation. i am finished it works now.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  # ...
  'django.core.context_processors.request',
  # ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks Dingo, i fount a tutorial here http://wiki.workassis.com/django-accessing-request-object-in-template/

Comment: In later versions of Djano, use instead: 'django.template.context_processors.request'

Answer (score 12):

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
instead of 
TEMPLATE_PROCESSORS

Comment: Thanks for editing the original question, although further updates render [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210678/888033) more accurate for contents in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 8):

Be advised that as of Django 1.8, this has changed to a "TEMPLATES" setting, and in the default configuration, the request processor is NOT included.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
            # list if you haven't customized them:
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

Just add the request processor back in to fix the issue:

```
'django.core.context_processors.request',
```

For more info, see the [Django Upgrading Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading).

Comment: Are you sure it is off by default in 1.8? https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.6/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py#L63 I've justed tested on 1.9.6 with `django-admin startproject` and it was there as well https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.6/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl#L63

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have the `request` variable available to the template?  What happens when you remove the line

```
'request':request,
```

that's different from when that line is present.  If your template loads the same either way, the problem is with your template.

Comment: For me it was that the function processing the request and updating context, passed context without the request. The request was lost so had to pass it manually to the function first because unlike render() it wasn't smart to pass request as well. Somewhat related to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
...
'yourfolder.yourfile.yourclass',
...
yourclass:

class AddRequestToTemplate:
process_templaet_response(self, request, response):
response.context_data['request']=request