# Setting a url parameter persistently

Tags: django, django-views

In my Django website, I have a certain parameter that I would like to set through url, or query string. E.g. `mysite.com/?param=value`. I want this value to be passed to all the views once it has been set - I can check it with `request.GET.get('param', 'default value')`. What would be the easiest way to do that in Django?

To make it more clear, here is an example - in the header of my site I have a dropdown menu with a list of years. Once I click on one of the choices I want this year to be carried over to all the other other parts of my website, i.e. `mysite.com/?year=1999`, then `mysite.com/somethingelse/?year=1999`, `mysite.com/onemorething/?year=1999` and so on. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One choice is to store this in `request.session` rather than in `request.GET`. It would still be set and accessed just as you would want it to be:

```
request.session["param"] = "my value"

request.session.get('param', 'default value')
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) for all the details of using sessions.

The exception would be if you specifically want this in the URL so that it is transparent and the user can change it.

ETA: Some answers to your questions:

1. If you really want a ?year=1999 URL to set the session variable in *any* view, you could create a custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) class. Middleware serves as a filter that can alter an HttpRequest before it reaches the view, or alter the HttpResponse that is returning from the view. In this case, you can have it check request.GET and set request.session if necessary, before it then executes the view. See the docs and be sure to read the details about middleware.
2. Having it in the URL is just not a good idea. There are ways around it but they're a lot of trouble.
3. You can use [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to [pass a request to a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702592/django-request-in-template) to be modified there. But why on earth would you do it there instead of in the view function?

Comment: +1 *absolutely* use request.session for this. Tacking a GET parameter onto every URL is just awful and likely to screw up your search engine results.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer. Let me clarify a few points.
1. Where do I have to set the session variable? Ideally, it should be set upon clicking on a link with a `?year=1999` part in it, but that could be in any of my views, not just one. 

2. It would be preferable to have this part in the url, but I can find a way around it since I have a menu that displays the current year in the header anyways.

3. Can I set a session variable from within a template?

Comment: `1.`My question now is which one is better for this - context processor or middleware? I'm thinking the former because there I can set a variable visible in templates.
`2.`I had a feeling it was a common practice. 
`3.`Because I could set it in the base template that other template extend instead of modifying every view I have (I have a few of those).
Currently, the way I see it is:
`1.`Create links that have likes of ?year=1999 
`2.`Check `request.GET` for the `year` key in context processor or middleware
`3.`Set`request.session['year']`
`4.`Pass this value to be used in templates.

Comment: 1. You make a good point about the context processor. That's a better option than middleware. 2. It depends how complicated your site is and how important the parameter is to it. 3. The value should certainly be used in templates, but as you say it should be set in the context processor.

Comment: The context processor approach doesn't work, because it seems like it is called after the view function, but I need to have the parameter value in the view so I have to use middleware after all...