# Django: how to get the name of the template being rendered

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm implementing a [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) `navbar` as show in this example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Items in a navbar are `<li>'s` , the "selected" item has the attribute `class="active"`:

```
  <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Link1 </a> </li>
  <li>                <a href="#"> Link2 </a> </li>
```

In Django these items will be within a template, which gets included by any templates that are supposed to display the navbar. I'm thinking about doing it this way:

```
<li> <a href="/"        class="{% if template_name == "home.djhtml"    %}active{% endif %}"> Home    </a> </li>
<li> <a href="about/"   class="{% if template_name == "about.djhtml"   %}active{% endif %}"> About   </a> </li>
<li> <a href="contact/" class="{% if template_name == "contact.djhtml" %}active{% endif %}"> Contact </a> </li>
```

I would like to know if there is a built-in way to get the `template_name` (that is, the template being rendered, as passed to `render_to_response()`, in `views.py`)

Sure, I could explicitly add a `template_name` variable to `render_to_response()`, which would solve the problem. But thinking about DRY I feel this shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit :)

Comment: You should not hardcode the urls in your templates (use the `{% url %}` templatetag instead), and you should rely on urls and `request.path` - not template names - to check if a links is active.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually use a custom template tag for this use case of adding a class to the active tab, menu item, etc.

```
@register.simple_tag
def active_page(request, view_name):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404
    if not request:
        return ""
    try:
        return "active" if resolve(request.path_info).url_name == view_name else ""
    except Resolver404:
        return ""
```

And here's a snippet from the top nav:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="{% active_page request "about" %}"><a href="{% url "about" %}">About</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. How should I access the `request` object: pass it to `render()` as a `dictionary` variable?

Comment: This is how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702592/django-request-in-template

Comment: @slumtrimpet has it.  It's provided by `RequestContext` assuming you're using it in your template rendering (Django Class Based Views do so automatically).

Comment: actually you should use here `resolve(request.path_info).view_name` instead of `url_name` if you're using url namespaces

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
class="{% if 'about' in request.path %}active{% endif %}"
```

It's a little shorter and more robust if the URI changes, just watch out if more than one path uses about.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much faster way, without creating any custom template tag!

```
<ul class = 'nav'>
    <li class="{% ifequal request.path 'about/'%} active {% endifequal%}">
        <a href="{% url "about" %}">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

just be aware about request.path. It might be with slash symbol at the beginning or without at the end of the path!

Answer (score 0):

Appending [prog.Dusans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19270142/3994485) answer for Django 1.7

```
settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'
)

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

template
{% ifequal request.path '/pathname'%}active{% endifequal%}
```

Best is to add it to the base template so you need only to do it once.

Like I this version more than [Kevin Stones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19270142/3994485) because you have to add almost equal code to the template and don't need a template tag after all.