# Django/Wagtail - How to create a conditional in template that checks for url path?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm struggling to finding a quick and easy solution to show HTML content based on a conditional that checks if the wagtail page is at root, aka `'/'`.

According to the Wagtail docs, I can also make this work using original request object from Django:

> Additionally request. is available and contains Django’s request
> object.

This is essentially what I want to do. I use the page object here from wagtail but it might be better if I used the request object from Django instead. How can I

```
{% if page.request.path == '/' %}

  <div> show something </div>

{% else %}

   #show nothing

{% endif %}
```

How can I structure a conditional to solve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: just use `request.path` instead of `page.request.path` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Access `request`

The request object can be accessed via `request` and not `page.request`.

A helpful tip is to add `{% debug %}` to see ALL the context that is available to the current template while working locally and debugging.

```py
{% if request.path == '/' %}

  <div> show something </div>

{% else %}

   #show nothing

{% endif %}
```

### More info

Within Wagtail the `request` object should be available to all templates, however you may need to enable this by following the instructions about [Using RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) in the Django docs.

Alternatively this [Django request in template answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2567234/8070948) provides a clear example of what to update in your settings file.